# how mac App get notification when user shake mouse(cursor become larger) in 10.11

Tags: macos, cocoa

when in 10.11, a new feature is brought: user can shake mouse to find cursor(cursor become larger).

my mac app want to get notify when user does this.

is there a way or any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple engineers have reviewed my request and have concluded that there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations.  Application's can not be notified when the user activates the cursor location assistance feature.